# how to use an enum switch statement in another function

Tags: swift, variables, google-places-api

First time working with an enum switch, so a few questions.

I'm looking to use this switch statement in a tableView function like so. First, do I declare variable open before using the enum switch? If so, am i passing in the open variable to the switch or creating the switch with a new name and by passing in the open variable? Third, how do I receive the value from the switch?

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FCT") as! FoodCellTwo

    let each = resultss[indexPath.row]

    var open: GMSPlacesOpenNowStatus = each.openNowStatus

  enum open : Int {


        /** The place is open now. */
        case yes

        /** The place is not open now. */
        case no

        /** We don't know whether the place is open now. */
        case unknown
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = each.name

    return cell
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID146

Comment: Its very clear cut, open status can be, open now i.e. YES, closed now, i.e. case NO and if the open status is not know, then is UNKNOWN. If you have specific syntax issue, you can refer the above link, or ask another question.

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the enum

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let status = openStatus // Get you open status or you could just use switch(openStatus)
        switch status {
        case .yes:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "This places is open"
        case .no:
            cell.textLabel?.text =  "This places is closed now"
        case .unknown:
            cell.textLabel?.text =  "No idea about open status"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

**Or**

I would suggest you to write an extension on `GMSPlacesOpenNowStatus` like this

```
extension GMSPlacesOpenNowStatus {
    func getStringTitle() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .yes:
            return "This places is open"
        case .no:
            return "This places is closed now"
        case .unknown:
            return "No idea about open status"
        }
    }
}
```

and use this extension like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let status = openStatus 
        cell.textLabel?.text = status.getStringTitle()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for, haha. Thank you so much, Bang! I decided to go with the first option, but for those of you looking to use the same, remember to specify your own UIlabel in code. Otherwise, your UI will be a mess during simulations.